# Select Query for VBA - SQL

Tags: ms-access, vba

Can someone correct this VBA Sql for me please

```
SQL = "SELECT * from [AnalyzedEmployeeStats] " & " WHERE [AnalyzedEmployeeStats].[UID] = " & "[AnalystInfo].[UID]" And "[AnalystInfo].[TLUID] = " & "' & TL_UID_Sending_Report & '"
```

I am getting "Type mismatch" error.

Below is what I have from Access SQL and it is working fine. Just need to change this to a vba-sql.

```
SELECT AnalyzedEmployeeStats.UserID, AnalystInfo.TLUID
FROM AnalyzedEmployeeStats, AnalystInfo
WHERE (((AnalyzedEmployeeStats.UserID)=[AnalystInfo].[UID]) AND ((AnalystInfo.TLUID)="abc123"));
```

"abc123" will be replaced by a string variable "TL_UID_Sending_Report"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portion of your statement saying

```
"[AnalystInfo].[UID]" And "[AnalystInfo].[TLUID] = "
```

is not valid as you cannot perform a logical operation such as `And` on `String` values.

I assume you meant to say

```
"[AnalystInfo].[UID] And [AnalystInfo].[TLUID] = "
```

This will then allow your statement to run, but it will set `SQL` to the string

```
SELECT * from [AnalyzedEmployeeStats]  WHERE [AnalyzedEmployeeStats].[UID] = [AnalystInfo].[UID] And [AnalystInfo].[TLUID] = ' & TL_UID_Sending_Report & '
```

That is not a likely SQL statement (unless you do have records where the TLUID field actually *does* have a value of " & TL_UID_Sending_Report & ").

I believe you want the following VBA statement:

```
SQL = "SELECT * from [AnalyzedEmployeeStats] WHERE [AnalyzedEmployeeStats].[UID] = [AnalystInfo].[UID] And [AnalystInfo].[TLUID] = '" & TL_UID_Sending_Report & "'"
```

which, when split into several lines to improve readability, becomes:

```
SQL = "SELECT * from [AnalyzedEmployeeStats] " & _
      " WHERE [AnalyzedEmployeeStats].[UID] = [AnalystInfo].[UID] And " & _
            " [AnalystInfo].[TLUID] = '" & TL_UID_Sending_Report & "'"
```

Comment: I am getting "Too few parameters. Expected 2". I updated the original question with SQL in Access. Please refer.

Comment: In that case, change the `SELECT * from [AnalyzedEmployeeStats]` to `SELECT AnalyzedEmployeeStats.UserID, AnalystInfo.TLUID FROM AnalyzedEmployeeStats, AnalystInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some unbalanced quotes. The word `And` is outside of your quotes and causing your error.

I think you also need to fix the quotes around `TL_UID_Sending_Report`, though I can't say for sure since I don't know what you're trying to do.

You might want to consider reading SQL from a .txt versus writing the SQL directly into VBA. If you ever change this query, you'll have a very annoying time trying to parse line continuations to change the bits you want.